# Is there any way alexa can add custom slot list dynamically through api call

Tags: alexa-skills-kit, alexa-slot

I have a scenario where the custom slot list values needs to updated dynamically from my api.my sample utterance must only be the slot value.If I am not using custom slot list as slot type,I am unable to build the skill.I should be able to read what ever user types.SampleUtterance is : {menu}.

Please let me know if we can have only slot in sample utterance and user can resd anything that he enters

Answer (score 0):

No there is no way to add custom slots dynamically at this moment. You have to add all custom slots manually

Comment: Is there any other way I can implement the above scenario